# Separation of concerns for a API or Service accepting query filters

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, software-design, separation-of-concerns, single-responsibility-principle

I always had this confusion which I couldn't reason more. Every time I think about it I go confused.

It is also hard to put in one line that's why the title is ambiguous.

All it is about where logic should go?

I have structured my backend architecture as below.

*Router routes to controller and controller communicate with a Service Provider or Service.*

i.e

For `/zones` router will route to `ZoneController` which loads off tasks to `ZoneService`
.

Likewise, `/banner-images` router will route to `BannerImageController` which loads off tasks to `BannerImageService`

Fair enough!

Now, suppose I need to fetch banner images at a zone so `banner-images?zone_id=2`

Where the logic should go? Which controller? Which Service?

Answer (score 0):

looks like the Zones here are first-class citizens. I guess one way would be `/zones/2/banner-images`.

What's the relationship between them? Can you have Banners without Zones? Are them somewhat independent, instead?

Comment: They are independent.

Comment: then it should be fine to use `banner-images?zone_id=2`. You could also give a look at GraphQL ( https://graphql.org/ )